# Creating and editing .text file from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, txt

I am making a web site that makes a record of the person who visit it

I have created a html form page that requests the name from the user

But I am unable to figure out how to keep record of it,maybe something like using making a text file and having javascript add names to it,but I am not sure how to do it

I am using Google drive and drv.tw to upload the site so I can't use any server side scripting language

Comment: Javascript is a client side langauge. It doesn't have access to the filesystem for security reasons. It's not possible to have it write a txt file (or any other file) on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Native JavaScript has not access to user's file system. But Node.js has, try this one if u can. In native JS you can use something like localStorage. But this solution only for your task, do not use this for production...

Comment: _"I can't use any server side scripting"_. And localStorage doesn't let him retrieve the data from other users. It's local. It's simply not possible given OP's situation.

Comment: If users will come from one local machine, local storage - solution. In another cases - yes, it's not possible)

Comment: Node.js does not work for google drive hosted websites either... Is there a way to make record without ANY server side language at all